# rspec describe a rake task namespace

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rake

I want to test a specific namespace of rake tasks and I am getting an error from rubocop.

```
desc 'This namespace is test'
namespace :test_namespace do

  task test_task: :environment do
```

On my rake task I have the following

```
RSpec.describe 'test_namespace' do
  describe 'test_task' do
```

The above gives me an error

```
The first argument to describe should be the class or module being tested.
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to pass the class straight into your describe line of your test, instead of a string. In your case:

```
RSpec.describe TestNamespace do
```